# What's an example of a Quotient/Identification Space for this topological space?

Tags: general-topology

I haven't been able to find an example with numbers anywhere on the internet and was hoping someone could help.

If I have $X = \{1, 2, 3\}, \tau = \{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1, 2\}, X\}$ as my topological space, then what is a quotient/identification space that I could have such that the function $f$ between the two is continuous?

I'm aware that the definition is motivated through the $R$-equivalence classes and having $f: X \to X/R$ be continuous, but a great example would help.

Answer (score 1):

Try the equivalence relation $R$ that is given by the partition $\{\{1\},\{2,3\}\}$. Then the topology on $X/R$ is by definition the collection of those subsets of $X/R$ whose union is a member of $\tau$. In this particular case you get a space that is isomorphic to the [Sierpinski space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space).